# GRASS console doesn't open

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm currently stuck in a project because whenever i try to open GRASS console (shell) it doesn't appear anything, and i cant find the reason why.

Im using QGIS Desktop 3.4.3 with GRASS 7.4.2

What i can do?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and find out how to write good questions. In particular give more information on what you are trying to do and how you are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, GRASS plugin is unmarked. So, at menu: Plugins-> Manage and Install Plugins, filtering by grass and, afterward, mark GRASS 7 plugin; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]